# MSBuild: Add and remove files to a msbuild 15 publish output @ BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish"

Tags: msbuild

I want to add and delete files when I publish in msbuild 15.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- My target, which is only executed on publication , Which is desirable in my case -->
  <Target Name="MyPrepareForPublish" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">

    <!-- Delete old files in wwwroot from Content -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\**"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- I Add and removes files to file system in wwwroot here , Exclude="@(Content)" prevents duplicates from outside wwwroot -->

    <!-- Adding new files to Content form wwwroot -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="wwwroot\**" Exclude="@(Content)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

 </Target>

</Project>
```

But when I remove and add files, I get an error  message :

```
(109,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\buildTest\WebsSrver\wwwroot\main.d158e9e1259986c4bd76.bundle.js" because it was not found.
```

My code deletes "main.d158e9e1259986c4bd76.bundle.js" and creates a new one with another name in MyPrepareForPublish.

The files are located in wwwroot im my dotnet core project.

So how do I specify what should be included in publish output ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what exactly is in that target? do you add/remove `Content` items? are you using the `2.0.0` SDK? (it has some fixes for this scenario)

Comment: are you using the 2.0.0 : yes , I think so 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets" and <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> in the topp of the proj file. what exactly is in that target ? : What target do you mean ?

Comment: I meant what your `MyPrepareForPublish` target does to modify files and the project

Comment: It removes files in wwwroot and adds new ones. The files will get new names which makes msbuild angry

Comment: do you update `Content` items or just modify the filesystem? Without the code, there is nothing to take a look at and investigate

Comment: yes i am modifying the ItemGroup Content , So it does not contain those old files. so it contain the new ones.

Comment: Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: I updated now, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Investigated and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding files during a pre-publish target, the SDK will also add corresponding `ContentWithTargetPath` items. However, the SDK does not track removals and modifications to `Content` items are irrelevant here since the publish targets use the `ContentWithTargetPath` only.

You should be able to work around your problems by removing the item groups removing and re-adding `Content` items and simply removing leftover `ContentWithTargetPath` after the custom steps have been run like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Remove="@(ContentWithTargetPath)" Condition="!Exists('%(FullPath)')" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The 2.0.0 SDK will add `ContentWithTargetPath` for newly generated files automatically.